# Comment with link to my library removed

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments, self-promotion, specific-comment

I posted a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010203/3397217) (answers now deleted) saying that out-of-the-box solutions for placeholders in `UITextView`s don't exist, but that there are libraries out there doing the job.
I recommended checking out a library called [LGTextView](https://github.com/LinusGeffarth/LGTextView) – which I made. In the comment, I clearly stated that it was made by me, so I made clear the affiliation:

> There is no out-of-the-box way to do that. There's libraries out there, such as LGTextView (mine)

<sup>*original comment*</sup>

As it's an open source library, there's no point in promoting it in any way. I was just trying to get OP help with their issue.

Why were my comments removed?

Comment: It is worth noting that the question has two answers (at -1 and -2 score) which are both deleted by their owners.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, anonymous users who visit that question will be redirected to the dupe anyway.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, they can be deleted at any time. Now, if it had been posted as an answer, then it'd be more permanent, of course.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Is that a good reason to delete useful content, though?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas A link to a library does not constitute an answer.  Content like that should be comments

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - "My library XYZ will solve your problem. Use it like this <examples>." is an answer.

Comment: @duplode - If it's an answer, there's a place for it (answers). If it's a question (for example, for clarification), then the answer should be editted into the question post. Anything else? Noise. If comments were meant to be permanent, the'd have been designed/implemented that way.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Useful content is not noise. Using the "comments are ephemeral" slogan in this way is putting means above ends.

Comment: Why do comments even exist in the first place if they are meant to be removed no matter the quality or relevance of the comment.

Comment: I find it hard to agree with *"it's an open source library, there's no point in promoting it in any way"*...

Comment: @chevybow Comments are intended as a way of asking for clarification or suggesting improvements.  Once a clarifying question is answered (by an edit to the question), it's obsolete.  Once an improvement is incorporated into the post, the comment suggesting it is obsolete.

Comment: @duplode - not quite sure what you mean by the last (not a native speaker of English). But really it comes down to the fact that this is a Q&A site, not a chat/forum. Discussions belong in a different venue. If it's not an answer, and it's not a request for clarification, then it's not appropriate for a Q&A. That's why comment threads can be moved to chat, when they devolve into conversations or debates. If they were intended to be more permanent, they would be structured more like answers.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I meant that the "comments are ephemeral" guideline is a way to easily get rid of unproductive discussions and other kinds of problematic comments. It shouldn't, however, be a justification to delete a lone, unproblematic and useful comment. No one benefits from that.

Comment: Well we don't know that his was the only comment. It could be that the question attracted lots of chatter and a mod came by responding to flags and wiped it all.

Comment: @duplode well, it was worse. It was flagged as unkind/harassment. How can someone suggesting a solution be unkind or an harasser?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Below the answer, this *was* my only comment. No chatter.

Answer (score -41, accepted):

It had two flags on it. In total you left two comments under the question and three comments under one of the answers. Basically saying it can't be done unless you use something like my library (linked) and then criticising one of the answers.

There was a flag on another of your comments under one of the answers. The other users felt you were pushing your project and bullying them for posting answers.

To be honest I was torn about whether to mark them as helpful or not. I made the decision to mark them as helpful, as it was two independent people raising similar flags, and the comment was a little (mildly) dismissive, so I marked them as helpful. Either way it won't affect your account. If you were to accrue abusive/unkind flags so that an auto flag is tripped, we would review the comments and that comment is not enough to warrant a mod warning (this is the back end result of comment flagging).

If I had dismissed the flag, I would have deleted the comment as no longer needed, as it really was plug for your own work  (open source or not)and there were two answers under the question, so it wasn't really needed.

To put it into perspective, there's hundreds of comment flags per day and if it's an edge case, sometimes it's impossible to make a call that will satisfy the community. As dismissing the flag can result in a meta post, deleting the comment can result in a meta post. The goal of the mod is to handle flags as expediently as possible and this is not black and white.

[image]

Comment: "Harassment, bigotry, or abuse", "unfriendly or unkind" - gosh, really? I can honestly not understand how any of those describe my comment.

Comment: Plus, sometimes there's tons of different answers on questions, all suggesting a different way to solve a problem. Why would this comment not be a valid way to add another solution to this question? I don't think it's "no longer needed", especially if all answers are deleted and so the question doesn't even have *any* answers beside my comment.

Comment: To see this in context, can you show me my comments to the deleted answers that made people feel like I *bullied* them? (I forgot what I posted and can't see it any longer)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I didn't flag the comments, I handled them. Understand it's the perspective of the other users on the site. A detached third party flagged the comment above and one of the answerers. So they both thought you were pushing your product and then being critical under one of the answers. It was taken you were trying to remove the answers in favour for people using your product. It's hard online, I get that. It was a ball line, really they were just no longer needed. Can you understand how someone else may have perceived that? I have to put myself in the flaggers shoes. Can you?

Comment: I'm trying. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth you left two critical comments under one of the answers. Pointing out multiple issues before the answerer was able to reply. It was that combined with your original comment that caused your comments to be flagged. I keep telling people, Leave one comment and move one, or at least wait for a reply. If the reply isn't favourable, move on, as there's no point arguing with someone who doesn't want to hear. Personally, you've not done anything "wrong" that will get you  into trouble. It's one of those things.. Trust me, it feels like the site is "sensitive" atm.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I appreciate that.  I'm happy to keep discussing this with you here, or in chat. I get it that it's hard. I do want you to feel supported too.

Comment: I do, thanks. And I think I understand how people felt with my comments.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth ping me here anytime you need some mod help or clarification.

Comment: "Pointing out multiple issues before the answerer was able to reply." How can it reply to issues I point out before I point them out?

Comment: With the risk of sounding harassing, a bigot or abusive: those flags are plain stupid.

Comment: @Braiam do I have to entertain this kind of nonsense? I am stating, write one comment and wait for a reply, don't harass people in the comments.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, it sounds childish actually. "those flags are plain stupid". Honestly. If some people have nothing better to do than to pick holes in small things. You're overlooking the whole scenario. Put yourself in someone else's shoes. The OP has done this, I'm sure all else can also. It's not black and white and frankly the amount of time wasted on meta debating trivia. What about the thousands of flags that were handled well and were clear cut? Some things are not clear cut.

Comment: I don't mind the deletion, that could be reasonable in context. I mind the helpful abusive flags on comments that objectively aren't even unfriendly. I'm used to unfair process from SO employees favouring the false victims crying loudest. I expect more from community moderators.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the joke is, I was unsure what to do with them. If you have any idea how many flags we handle maybe you'd be more supportive. It's so easy to criticise from the sidelines. I've handled 30 thousand flags since becoming moderator and the flack I get on meta is disgusting. You'd think I wrote the blog and was the cause of the policy changes. Well I didn't, I was thrown into the position when there was a massive change on the site and a great increase in comment flags. I and the other mods are doing our best. If we decline flags that ends up on meta and we cop it. I'm drawing a line.

Comment: I know you guys are. And I know you're innocent in policy changes (by the way I heard there _were_ no policy changes since CoC == Be Nice). And I know you've been raising your voice against stupid things the company has been doing. I've been happy to see that. Hence my original remark merely saying that the flags were stupid. You didn't raise them.

Comment: @YvetteColomb If you're unsure of what to do with a flag, as you mentioned,, it might be a good idea to not do anything at that point in time. No decision is better than a questionable one and you can go back to it later, or let someone with more objectivity handle the flag. From what I've read, the ones raising those flags are guilty of what they were flagging, which is ironic IMHO.

Comment: @code_dredd the people who raised the flags did nothing. You don't know who raised the flags. So I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion. Honestly, whether the flags were declined or dismissed, the comments were going to be deleted anyway.

Comment: @YvetteColomb _"You don't know who raised the flags. So I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion"_ Easy, by raising the flags about the comment being "bigoted, harassing, or abusive" they themselves were being at least one of those things. It doesn't matter that I don't know who they were or what they had done, if anything. That is what my original comment intended to communicate.

Comment: The fact that you had any uncertainty to whether these flags should be marked helpful or not is deeply troubling to me. These are wildly off-mark for this specific comment. If there were problems of tone in other comments, that's a different issue - but marking these flags as helpful is patently absurd and makes a mockery of the intended use of a "harrassment, bigotry or abuse" flag.

Comment: You say that "The goal of the mod is to handle flags as expediently as possible", but I think that handling flags as **appropriately** as possible is much more important. A lot of your responses here have a tone of "there's so many flags to handle, cut me some slack" - but speaking for myself at least, I'd rather see mods take fewer actions and focus on getting it right more of the time when they do, rather than focusing on quantity of moderation.

Comment: And one last thing: you say "I've handled 30 thousand flags since becoming moderator and the flack I get on meta is disgusting. You'd think I wrote the blog and was the cause of the policy changes.". I think it's important to emphasize that you aren't just being criticized by people who hate the new policies. Frankly, I think that the emphasis on moderating potentially harassing language is well needed. If anything it seems like *you're* the one trying to redirect and scapegoat the new policy in this case where it's not central to the actual issue, which is simply re: a wildly inaccurate flag.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how you could think that marking these flags helpful could possibly be a good idea. If there are any processes on the back end that "learn" from comment deletion (I don't know, but I think it is likely), they would be fed false positives / bad information. Even if there aren't, as you say enough of these will raise auto-flags, and if it starts happening more that means more false auto-flags until they stop having any meaning. At the very least it proves to the flagger that their flags were reasonable, which means they will continue flagging as such.

Comment: The way you placed the picture of the flags as one of the first things in your answer gives the tone that you find those flags the most important factor. However, after further reading the answer, it seems like you did it because of other reasons. Can I suggest converting the image to text to *less* emphasize on it?

Comment: Can I flag the flags?

Comment: "I have to put myself in the flaggers shoes" Not really. Judgements should be *objective* and for good reason. Site users can over-react - those with moderation duties shouldn't over-react, as well. Objective judgement can understand overreaction and not "punish" people for flagging inappropriately in a moment of pique, while still handling the flags in a reasonable manner. Supporting unreasonable flagging will cause more work for the moderators, in the long run.

Comment: I find it incredible that these flags were actually assumed to have been made in good faith. I guess the "put yourself in someone else's shoes" is only valid for people who flagged, not for the people who actually produce factual, completely acceptable content, and later see they're being targeted for no reason. Sorry to pile on but... Woa.

Answer (score 24):

I thought a moment about Yvette Colomb actions and her answer here, and, despite the amount of downvotes that she received, it may have been the right call to delete this specific comment. Here is why:

[The question it duplicates has 73 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview): this means it is an incredibly popular issue with many possible workarounds (and easy ones, otherwise there wouldn't be so many answers):

1. The part of the comment "*there is no out-of-box way to do that*" seems hasty as there are some short answers, and even one-liners like `[myTextView addSubView:myPlaceHolderLabel]`.
2. As the owner of the linked lib, Linus Geffarth could have shared the code as an answer instead of a link-only comment.
3. If all the libs solving this question were advertised in separate comments, it would be flooded with link-only comments. Better to link to an exhaustive **list** of libs, like https://cocoapods.org with the search term of "PlaceHolderTextView"
   [image: PlaceHolderTextView results on cocoapods.org]

Comment: Just to reiterate: deletion yes, "harassing, bigotry or abuse" no.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. 1) A truly "out-of-the-box" solution would be `textView.placeholder = ""`. Since that is not implemented, there is no such solution. Easy solutions are still not out-of-the-box. 2) Yes, I could have shared the code to make it an answer, but that's why I made my link a comment, not an answer. 3) The duplicate has 73 answers. Each are posted individually (of course!), so why should I not be allowed to post a link as comment, even though the link doesn't cover 100% of the solutions out there?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Because providing (incomplete) answers in comments is discouraged. One of the reasons for that is that comments don't have full voting, which makes quality control much harder. With a little copy&paste from your library's sample code, you could have posted your comment as an answer instead. Then it would not have been deleted (no longer needed does apply to the comment, but not answers) and people could have voted on its usefulness.

Comment: *"despite the amount of downvotes that she received"* - Objection: the amount of downvotes the **answer** received.

Comment: @Gimby I think the voting is personal.  The answers are in agreement. One had 76 downvotes, the other has 8. One also has a multiple insulting comments, some deleted about when the next mod election will be etc etc. Par for the course.

Comment: @YvetteColomb you are probably right that in this case a larger than usual amount of people were doing that. But definitely not everyone.

Comment: @Gimby no not everyone. A trend.